# RMS calculation of signal with high crest factor up to 10 MHz

Tags: dsp, rms

I'm attempting to measure the RMS of an AC signal with a crest factor of up to 10, at frequencies of up to 10 MHz. From my brief research I can see many ICs that work well above 100 MHz (designed for RF stuff) and many that work below 1 MHz. I can't seem to find any IC that works in the range I need.

Would a DSP be a good solution to this problem? What sort of frequency does the DSP need to run at to accurately measure my 10 MHz signal? I can't find any simple information telling me this sort of thing and I wanted to know how possible it is before I start any in depth reading, since I know next to nothing about DSPs right now.

Thanks.

Edit: LTC1968 is about he closest I can find, but it specifies crest factors of less than 5, and it's 3dB error bandwidth is 15MHz, which is a little close to my 10 Mhz requirement, but I think I can combine it with an RF chip

Comment: What makes you think that the 100 MHz chips can't work at 10 MHz?

Comment: Because most of the RF style chips (such as LT5581) specify a range (such as 10MHz -> 6GHz) and so I'm assuming that's where they're accurate, whereas I'm looking for something that will work from a much lower frequency (say 10 kHz) up to 10 MHz, I'm not sure how accurate those higher frequency ones will be down there.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your requirements? Is this a laboratory measurement, or something that you want to design into a product? What kind of transient response do you need at the output? What is the range power levels you are measuring? What are your accuracy requirements?

Comment: A crest factor of ten means spikey signals, how fast are the edges?  (lots of fast opamps in that range.)

Comment: Bolometer-based RMS meters come to mind.

Comment: Many oscilloscopes will do this for you. But if you want a circuit, I think you basically have two choices: Analog to Digital followed by processor (possibly DSP) and bolometer (as Nick suggested). Basically, terminate the signal at 50 Ohms, and measure the heating of the 50 Ohm resistor. There are resistors specific for this purpose.

Comment: @mkeith  Could you post a link to a specialized bolometer resistor, if possible?  I haven't come across such a thing yet.  I'm curious, but couldn't find it with google.

Comment: I came a cross it looking for something else. It was just a 50 Ohm resistor, but the datasheet mentioned that it was for power measurement. It specifically mentioned the bandwidth, and it was up to several GHz. Just now I took a quick look at digikey and couldn't find it. Sorry. They do have RF termination resistors.

Comment: @DaveTweed It's intended to be designed into a product, so I can't just use a piece of bench equipment that can do it (of which I've found several). My accuracy requirement is less than 1%, and a transient response of less than 10 seconds is my only requirement there.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold 10 MHz is the fastest harmonic I'm expecting

Comment: OK if 10 MHz is the highest frequency, then I like Nick A's bolometer idea. (With opamps to gain up the signal.)  (providing the thermal environment for the device is not too extreme.)  HP had an old power meter that (I think) balanced an RF heated resistor(?) against a DC heated one, and then measured the DC power for equal temperature.  Getting the thermal design correct will take some work.  (I can think of lots of variations on this theme.. keep DC power constant and change RF gain...etcl.)